# Python subprocess Popen argument issue not parsing full string?

Tags: python

I am using subprocess.Popen to start a process with a argument. However, it is cutting off the argument and driving me crazy! lol.

```
randport = random.randint(3000, 7000)
args='-p '+str(randport)+' --base-path /wd/hub'
subprocess.Popen(['appium', args], cwd="C:\\Users\\Computer", shell=True)
```

Example of what is actually being executed:
Let's say randport got generated to be 3333

```
subprocess.Popen(['appium', '-p 3333'], cwd="C:\\Users\\Computer", shell=True)
```

What should of been executed:

```
subprocess.Popen(['appium', '-p 3333 --base-path /wd/hub'], cwd="C:\\Users\\Computer", shell=True)
```

Comment: What you're doing will pass that whole string as the first argument.   That's not what you want.  Put each word in a separate list element.  Remember, what you're passing there IS the "argv" array.  Alternatively, you could skip the list and just pass the string `'appium '+args`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When passing arguments as a list, you have to pass every single space-separated argument separately:

```py
subprocess.Popen(['appium', '-p', '3333', '--base-path', '/wd/hub'], cwd="C:\\Users\\Computer", shell=True)\
```

This is to prevent shell injection.  On the other hand, you're using `shell=True`.  You almost certainly don't want that, but if you *do*, you can simply pass a string instead of a list, since you're vulnerable to shell injection anyhow.

(If your command is a constant string like this, injection protection is moot.)

Comment: Doesn't work [ERROR] Unrecognized arguments: /wd/hub

Comment: That's not a python error, but related to whatever `appium` is, or how you passed the argument (should it be `--base-path="/wd/hub"`?)